# Compilar várias classes Java no cmd?

Tags: java, compilação, cmd

Como compilar vários arquivos `.class` em java pelo `cmd`? Tentei e ele informa que não foi possível localizar a main.

Comment: Poste o comando que usou.

Comment: Está usando 'java' ou 'javac' para compilar?

Answer (score 6):

Você pode usar estes dois comandos:

```
javac *.java
```

ou

```
javac arquivo1.java arquivo2.java main.java
```

*Eles devem estar na mesma pasta.

Pergunta semelhante no SOen [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22340872/how-do-i-compile-multiple-java-files-using-cmd)